# moving a box in the air with gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i want to move a simple box in the space, with [gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo). i launched a simple world and a simple box not affected by gravity. I want to move the box in the three dimensions.

how can i do it?

by kayboard with a node? by services and applying wrenches?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12340/moving-a-box-in-the-air-with-gazebo/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at this tutorial:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API#Apply_Wrenches_to_Links

---

Originally posted by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) with karma: 58 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0